# Error code 32 - Rheem PowerVent water heater

Tags: water-heater

My Rheem PowerVent water heater is flashing error code 32. I have bypassed all the sensors, and everything checks out. What else is left to try except the board?

Answer (score 1):

From what I could find it indicates a problem with the heat exchanger thermistor. If you bypassed the sensor properly (shorting or open does not work) you need to replace the PCB (Printed Circuit Board). This is what I found with Google: "Rheem error code 32 means there is a problem with the heat exchanger thermistor. ... If the temperature is not within specifications, replace the thermistor, and if it is, you may have to replace the PCB. A temperature of 32°F means the thermistor is not connected correctly, and 199°F indicates a direct short.May 7, 2021".